# Setting segmented control at the centre of the tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working with the segmented control. I am using the following code to set it  at the left of the tab.

```
 segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
 segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle =
 UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
 segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,10,220,35);
 [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Male" atIndex:0
 animated:YES];
 [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Female" atIndex:1
 animated:YES];
 segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
 [segmentedControl setMomentary:NO];
 [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
 initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
 [segmentedControl release];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
 [segmentBarItem release];
```

My question is how can we set it at the center of the tab bar, as it is not taking the CGRect() values to set the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to add the *UISegmentedControl* to *UINavigationBar* not *UITabBar*. If you want it at the center you can set it as the *titleView* of *navigationItem*.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```